# zabbix-server display error message

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7, zabbix

All,
I've faced a zabbix-server error, which run on centos 7.It shows **"Zabbix-server is not running, the information may not be current"** in my web browser. Zabbix-version is 3.4.4. Mysql version 15.1 Distrib 5.5.56 Mariadb. Server version 5.5.56-Mariadb MariaDB server. I've tried alot of discussion in google, but they did not solve my error.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost always caused by one of:

- Zabbix server is not running
- host or port in the frontend configuration is incorrect
- firewall prevents connections from the frontend to that port
- SELinux prevents connections from the frontend to that port
- there are not enough Zabbix trappers to handle connections from the frontend